# Images in Django posts

Tags: django, image, django-models

What is the most *painless* and simple way to insert uploaded images in other models, i.e. blog posts or text.

I need a simple solution for blog posts and static pages with markdown and I would like to be able to implement the insert-image functionality, similar to WP.

I am sure that somewhere someone has proposed a simple and valid solution to this problem, but I just can't seem to be able to find it.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend taking a look at django-adminfiles: https://bitbucket.org/carljm/django-adminfiles/. This handles the functionality you are describing and there's even a nice screen cast showing how it works: http://vimeo.com/8940852